# Como notificar o usuário que um arquivo FTP está atualizado?

Tags: android, ftp

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em android  que lista e abre arquivos de um diretório via FTP

Eu preciso que minha aplicação notifique o usuário que existe uma versão atualizada de um arquivo por meio de um toast ou qualquer outra forma,ou seja,quando abrir a aplicação apareça uma mensangem escrita "example.pdf está atualizado"

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa de uma biblioteca que forneça uma API para acessar o servidor FTP e retornar as informações necessárias a respeito dos arquivos presentes nele. Então toda vez que o seu aplicativo executar, ele irá se conectar ao FTP, ler as informações sobre os arquivos (timestamp, etc.) e informar ao usuário se houver alguma novidade em relação ao arquivo armazenado localmente.

Tente por exemplo o FTP client da Apache Commons: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/

**Observação:** Esse talvez não seja o jeito melhor de se fazer isso. O ideal, creio eu, seria disponibilizar um web service que traz as informações dos arquivos armazenados no servidor FTP. Aí quem obtém informações dos arquivos é o web service e não o aplicativo Android (seja via conexão com o FTP ou então lendo os dados dos arquivos locais, se o servidor de aplicação que disponibiliza o web service estiver na mesma máquina que o FTP). Uma conexão com o FTP para baixar o arquivo só seria feita se houvesse realmente necessidade de baixá-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Li seu post, e acredito que você deva escrever um script que leia os arquivos em /var/log de seu servidor linux se for o caso, por exemplo em minha maquina fica em /var/log/proftpd, dentro tem 2 arquivos system.log e transfer.log, interpretando o texto contido nestes arquivos pode manter seus usuarios informados.